# Removing Nulls and Fixing Alignment

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server and I made the query using SMSS. I am not a full time SQL user, and I am trying to make some dashboards for our workers using SQL as the data collector with this query below.

The query that is almost working, but I need to get all my results to go in paired rows, instead of showing nulls. Here is the query I wrote:

```
SELECT convert(varchar(11), start_time, 103) AS Date, DATENAME(weekday, start_time) AS Week_Day,
CASE WHEN CAST(start_time AS time) = '05:00:00'
THEN name
END AS 'Morning',
CASE WHEN CAST(start_time AS time) ='12:59:59'
THEN name
END AS 'Afternoon',
CASE WHEN CAST(start_time AS time) = '20:59:59'
THEN name
END AS 'Evening'
FROM [somedb].[dbo].[tb_some_table]
WHERE [start_time] >= dateadd(day, 2-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate()))
AND [start_time] < dateadd(day, 9-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate()))
```

Which gives me a result like this:

```
Date       Week_Day Morning Afternoon Evening
24/08/2020 Monday   Fred    NULL      NULL
24/08/2020 Monday   Markus  NULL      NULL
24/08/2020 Monday   NULL    Chuck     NULL
24/08/2020 Monday   NULL    Bill      NULL
24/08/2020 Monday   NULL    NULL      John
24/08/2020 Monday   NULL    NULL      Wayne
```

But, I am trying to get this:

```
Date       Week_Day Morning Afternoon Evening
24/08/2020 Monday   Fred    Chuck     John
24/08/2020 Monday   Markus  Bill      Wayne
```

Can anyone help me? :/

EDIT: Data looks like this:

The data looks like this if I run a select:

```
start_time              end_time                name

2020-08-24 05:00:00.000 2020-08-24 12:59:59.000 Frank
2020-08-24 05:00:00.000 2020-08-24 12:59:59.000 Markus
2020-08-24 12:59:59.000 2020-08-24 20:59:59.000 Chuck
2020-08-24 12:59:59.000 2020-08-24 20:59:59.000 Bill
2020-08-24 20:59:59.000 2020-08-25 05:00:00.000 John
2020-08-24 20:59:59.000 2020-08-25 05:00:00.000 Wayne
```

Comment: What relationship does Fred have with Chuck and John, and Markus with Bill and Wayne? Why not Fred, Bill and John, for example?

Comment: Also, what does your data look like *before* your undesired results?

Comment: Hi, Frank and Markus are working Monday morning together, Chuck and Bill are working Monday afternoon together, and Jpn and Wayne are working together on Monday Evening.

Comment: What does that have to do what th the relationship between Fred and Chuck? They are on the same row, so what why are they together? Why not Fred and Bill, as I asked?

Comment: [Edit] your question, don't dump that in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want aggregation:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, start_time) as date,
       DATENAME(weekday, MIN(start_time)) AS Week_Day,
       MAX(CASE WHEN CAST(start_time AS time) = '05:00:00' THEN name END) AS Morning,
       MAX(CASE WHEN CAST(start_time AS time) = '12:59:59' THEN name END) AS Afternoon,
       MAX(CASE WHEN CAST(start_time AS time) = '20:59:59' THEN name END) AS Evening
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY start_time ORDER BY start_time) as seqnum
      FROM [somedb].[dbo].[tb_some_table] t
      WHERE start_time >= dateadd(day, 2-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date, getdate())) AND
            start_time < dateadd(day, 9-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date, getdate()))
     ) t
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, start_time), seqnum;
```

Note that you want multiple rows per date.  The `ROW_NUMBER()` is determining that.

Notes:

- You don't need to convert a date to a string to extract the date component.  Use `convert()` only if you really want the date in a particular format.
- It seems odd that the times are exact.  I would expect ranges.  If that is really the case, then ask a new question.  It would change the query.
- Only use single quotes for string and date constants.  Do not use them for column names -- that will just lead to hard-to-debug errors when (one day) you think you are referring to a column using single quotes.

Comment: As usual, too fast for me.... Congratz on hitting the big 1000K :-)

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response and for all the pointers, thank you very much. I am still learning SQL and the query was the result of a morning full of Goolging, so I do appreciate your help. 
When running the query I am receiving the following error, 
Msg 107, Level 15, State 1, Line 39
The column prefix 't' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 45
No column name was specified for column 1 of 't'.

What does the 't' represent?

Comment: You need to add `DATENAME(weekday, start_time)` to the `GROUP BY` here, or change it to `DATENAME(weekday, CONVERT(date,start_time))` in the `SELECT`

Comment: `t` is the alias Gordon has used, @G-Man83 . Aliasing is a very basic part of SQL, and it's very good practice to use *good* aliasing.